Georgia Tech thesis template issues with optidef (calc) and subsection
The issues & solutions
I encountered 2 challenges with the Georgia Tech thesis template:

When using the optidef package (and probably other packages too), there are conflicts with the calc package it includes (it seems the calc package is notoriously fragile) which cause errors (see below).
One classic fix seems to be to use etoolbox robustify (e.g. unaffiliated github commit).  Paste this AFTER the problematic import (e.g. after \usepackage{optidef}).
\usepackage{etoolbox} % Make robust some counters that are made fragile by `calc`
\robustify\setcounter
\robustify\addtocounter
\robustify\setlength
\robustify\addtolength


With certain versions of TexLive / various packages, the subsection command inside the thesisbody environment (Line 123 of gatechthesis.cls) throws errors due to \hspace inside a \uline.  Referring to this answer, one fix is to place the hspace inside an mbox:
% \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\uline{\thesubsection}}{0em}{\uline{\hspace{1em}##1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\uline{\thesubsection}}{0em}{\uline{\mbox{\hspace{1em}}##1}}



MWE
This appears on the March 2024 update of the georgia tech thesis template (overleaf link).  Here is a MWE example where I just added \usepackage{optidef}, i.e.
\documentclass[12pt]{gatechthesis}

\input{imports}

% preamble
% ... rest of file is the same as stock template

It produces errors due to calc/optidef, but I can't seem to reproduce the "subsection" error on overleaf (same exact project throws errors on my local computer pdflatex 2021.8.23, ulem 2019/11/18).
Full error messages
I include the full error messages here for SEO:
The optidef/calc issue:
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                    \begingroup 
l.57 ...up \aftergroup \calc@B \calc@A \begingroup
                                                    \aftergroup \calc@B \calc...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                    \afterassignment 
l.57 ...ftergroup \calc@B \calc@A \afterassignment
                                                    \def {\GenericError {(cal...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    \let \@err@               ...
l.57 ...ion.}{I expected to see one of: + - * / )}
                                                    }\calc@A 1!\global \calc@A...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

The subsection issue:
./chapters/1_intro.tex:17: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...alty \ifnum \lastkern =\thr@@ \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \ifdim \wd \UL@box...
l.17 \subsection{Social Implications}
                                     
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./chapters/1_intro.tex:17: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...num \lastkern =\thr@@ \egroup \egroup 
                                                  \ifdim \wd \UL@box =\z@ \e...
l.17 \subsection{Social Implications}
                                     
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./chapters/1_intro.tex:17: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.17 \subsection{Social Implications}
                                     
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

./chapters/1_intro.tex:17: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.17 \subsection{Social Implications}
                                     
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.


As stated in the question, add the following block:
\usepackage{optidef} % <-- This was your offending import
\usepackage{etoolbox} % Make robust some counters that are made fragile by `calc`
\robustify\setcounter
\robustify\addtocounter
\robustify\setlength
\robustify\addtolength

And edit the gatechthesis.cls subsection definition:
% \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\uline{\thesubsection}}{0em}{\uline{\hspace{1em}##1}} % <-- old
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\uline{\thesubsection}}{0em}{\uline{\mbox{\hspace{1em}}##1}} % <-- new

